# Is SO3 an ion or a molecule?

Tags: ions, molecules, molecular-structure

Earlier I thought that $\ce{SO3^{2-}}$ (sulfite) is an ion with -2 charge but today I read on internet $\ce{SO3}$ (sulfur trioxide) is a molecule with no charge. How can this be possible? Please explain knowing that I am only a student of 10th standard (use normal chemistry concepts as far as possible).

Comment: Search in Google for their molecular structures. You'll understand the difference.

Comment: For one thing, $\ce{SO3^{2-}}$ has two extra electrons, so it's an ion. $\ce{SO3}$ is a neutral molecule. There are a different number of electrons, so they're just different.

Comment: The key is that they actually have different molecular formulae and are thus different compounds. Remember that charge counts ;)

Comment: It's pretty hard to explain this to a 10th grader. Just wait for a while, 11th grade teaches you all about different types of bonds. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll give you the structures. Then you'll understand everything:

**Resonance structures of $\ce{SO3^{2-}}$ ion:**

[image]

**Structure of Sulfur Trioxide:**

[image]

The absence of a double bond between two oxygen atoms in sulfite ion shows why it is bivalent.

Comment: I don't think that is the structure of $\ce{SO3}$. The real structure has one double bond and 2 dative bonds.